# Using dictionaries and compound field format() with Integer key stored as String

Tags: python, string, dictionary

If a dictionary has an **integer key stored as a string** `{'0': 'foo'}` how would you reference that in [Compound Field Names](http://getpython3.com/diveintopython3/strings.html#compound-field-names) using `.format()`?

I get that it may be un-pythonic *(and bad programming)* to have a dict with such keys...but in this case, it's also not possible to use this way:

```
>>> a_dict = {0: 'int zero',
...           '0': 'string zero',
...           '0start': 'starts with zero'}
>>> a_dict
{0: 'int zero', '0': 'string zero', '0start': 'starts with zero'}
>>> a_dict[0]
'int zero'
>>> a_dict['0']
'string zero'
>>> " 0  is {0[0]}".format(a_dict)
' 0  is int zero'
>>> "'0' is {0['0']}".format(a_dict)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
KeyError: "'0'"
>>> "'0start' is {0[0start]}".format(a_dict)
"'0start' is starts with zero"
```

`{0[0]}.format(a_dict)` will always refer to the key `int 0` even if there isn't one, so at least that's consistent:

```
>>> del a_dict[0]
>>> a_dict
{'0': 'string zero', '0start': 'starts with zero'}
>>> "{0[0]}".format(a_dict)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
KeyError: 0L
```

(And yes, I know I could just do `'%s' % a_dict['0']` if required.)

Comment: Additionally, from [PEP 3101](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3101/): `Because keys are not quote-delimited, it is not possible to specify arbitrary dictionary keys (e.g., the strings "10" or ":-]") from within a format string.`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`str.format`, unlike e.g. ["f-strings"](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/), doesn't use the full parser. To pull out the relevant bits of the [grammar](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-string-syntax):

```
replacement_field ::=  "{" [field_name] ["!" conversion] [":" format_spec] "}"
field_name        ::=  arg_name ("." attribute_name | "[" element_index "]")*
element_index     ::=  digit+ | index_string
index_string      ::=  <any source character except "]"> +
```

A `field_name` surrounded by square brackets is an `element_index`, which is either:

1. one or more digits (`digit+`, like `0` - but only if they're *all* digits, which is why `0start` falls into the second case); or
2. a sequence of *"any source character except "]""*.

Therefore for `0['0']` the `field_name` is `"'0'"`, **not** `'0'`.

> ... an expression of the form `'[index]'` does an index lookup using
> `__getitem__()`.

For `"'0' is {0['0']}".format(a_dict)` the replacement is `a_dict.__getitem__("'0'")`, and there's no way within the grammar to select the actual `a_dict['0']`.

Comment: I see you moved your answer here. Thanks for the additional info :-)

Comment: @aneroid no problem, thanks for finding (and writing!) the dupe.

Comment: Worth adding wrt the `str.format()` behaviour seen by the user: String keys are _auto-quoted_ for the lookup while Integer keys (or numeric keys) are _never-quoted_ for the lookup. That makes it impossible to have "an integer as a string" key for `str.format()`. A _sad_ workaround would be to _extra-quote_ the "integer as a string" keys like `"'0'": 'more stringified zero'` but even that could fail since the inner quote (single-quoted or double-quoted) has to match with how it's referenced in `str.format()`, which is just painful and error-prone.

Comment: @aneroid nothing is "auto-quoted"; remember we're starting with a string, so it's `template[leftBracketIndex + 1:rightBracketIndex]` - `"{a['0']}"[3:6] == "'0'"`. It's the *numerical* case that's special, if and only if all characters in the result string are digits, you get `int(template[leftBracketIndex + 1:rightBracketIndex])` instead.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot. You'd need to pass in an additional argument to format.

```
>>> "'0' is {0[0]} {1}".format(a_dict, a_dict['0'])
```

Comment: **You cannot** being key here. No pun intended.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: I figured out the problem. It is calling dict.**getitem** with the string "'0'", not '0' as expected. Therefore this is impossible. Sorry.

Comment: What prevents it is that indexing in the format specification is a bit half-assed, and doesn't require a delimiter, so it's ambiguous here, and therefore you just need to pick one or the other.

Comment: Except that it says that index_string can include any character besides ]. And it is calling getitem with the string 0 as can be confirmed by passing in a custom class.

Comment: @Antimony Nice idea to test it using classes. +1