# How to convert this f-string into str.format

Tags: python

In `str.format` I can't get the value from a dict with the string key, both raises exception:

```
>>> d = {1: "one", "2": "two"}
>>> 'int {d[1]}'.format(d=d)
'int one'
>>> 'int {d[1]}, str {d["2"]}'.format(d=d)
KeyError: '"2"'
>>> 'int {d[1]}, str {d[2]}'.format(d=d)
KeyError: 2
```

One way looks for key `'"2"'` and other way for key `2`, but how do you look for key `"2"`? I mean using the format string itself, not just extracting it from outside the `str.format` template.

With f-string it can access the values in dicts like normal:

```
>>> f'int {d[1]}, str {d["2"]}'
'int one, str two'
```

Comment: `str.format` isn't using the full parser, there are things that just aren't possible.

Comment: `'int {}, str {}'.format(d[1], d["2"])`

Comment: Upvoted the question. I'm really curious how the `d["2"]` part is actually parsed and why exactly `.format` is failing this way.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19796123/python-string-format-calling-a-function

Comment: @Norrius: It's all in [the format string syntax docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#grammar-token-element-index). Short version: It supports numeric indexing as a special function; despite superficially similar syntax, it's not the same as subscripting in normal Python code.

Comment: Exact dupe: [Using dictionaries and compound field format() with Integer key stored as String](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11662565/1431750)

Comment: @aneroid OK, answer on the dupe is useless though. It only shows the obvious workaround and doesn't even explain anything.

Comment: @COVFEFE-19 The answers and _comments_ explain that "Integers as Strings" can't be used for dictionary keys to work with `str.format()`. And [the answer by @jonrsharpe](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66162690/1431750) provides that in more detail, including _**why**_.

Comment: @aneroid I think I am going crazy but the answer looked completely different a moment ago

Comment: @COVFEFE-19 You're not going crazy :-) I updated the "accepted answer" to one jonrsharpe posted, since it included details on the _why_, apart from [my comment on the question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11662492/using-dictionaries-and-compound-field-format-with-integer-key-stored-as-string/11662565#comment15457015_11662492) and the other answers which did provide some explanation. Specifically, that it _can't_ be done, except via the workarounds mentioned here and there. (Usually it's worth seeing those for details about the answer.)

Comment: OK I see now. This question got closed and answer that was briefly appeared here moved to an 8 years old question. Kind of strange how this site works, to close the new question and remove answer, onto old question with Python 2 code when f-strings didn't even exist back then. Why not just leave the new answer on the new question???