# When I run this python command in the interpretor, I get a TypeError

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, list, python-2.7

So I was running the command `'first={0[0]}, last={0[-1]}'.format(somelist)` where `somelist = ['s','p','a','m']`. I get an error which says `TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str`.

Instead when I run the same command by changing `0[-1]` to `0[1]`, it works and the output is `'first=s, last=p'`. Since `somelist` is a list, negative indices should work.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/66162690/3001761 - numerical "keys" are special-cased, but only if *all* characters are digits (`-` doesn't count).

Comment: @jonrsharpe thank you. I found out that negative indices are not accepted here. It seems like a bug. Even reported here - https://bugs.python.org/issue7951